# Using echo or printf to print out new line and carriage returns as \n and \r

Tags: shell-script, echo

I am using `echo` to debug my shell script and would like to know how to use `echo` to also print out the new line `\n` and/or carriage return `\r` characters as well in the form `\n` and `\r` in order to inspect strings. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just use `\n` and `\r` with `echo -e`.

Comment: print them out how? if they're in variables, `echo` and `printf` would by default print them out quite literally, as the actual CR and LF characters. Is that what you want, or do you want to have them in some other format, e.g. as `\r` and `\n` (backslash and the letters r or n). Quoted as valid input for the shell, or not?

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes I should clarified that yes they're printed out but I mean printed out in another form such \r and \n

Comment: @EduardoTrápani These strings already contain \n and/or \r so I am trying to print these except have them print as \n and \r instead of just new lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU implementation of `printf` or the `printf` builtin of ksh93, zsh or bash would do something like that with `printf %q`, by outputting strings as if quoted by the `$'...'` ksh93 quotes when they contain control characters such as *carriage return* or *linefeed*:

```
$ string=$'foo\rbar\n' ksh93 -c 'printf "%q\n" "$string"'
$'foo\rbar\n'
$ string=$'foo\rbar\n' zsh -c 'printf "%q\n" "$string"'
foo$'\r'bar$'\n'
$ string=$'foo\rbar\n' bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$string"'
$'foo\rbar\n'
$ string=$'foo\rbar\n'; /usr/bin/printf "%q\n" "$string"
'foo'$'\r''bar'$'\n'
```

In the `zsh` shell, you can also use the `qqqq` parameter expansion flag to use those `$'...'` quotes unconditionally:

```
$ s1=$'\r\n' s2=foobar
$ print -rC1 -- ${(qqqq)s1} ${(qqqq)s2}
$'\r\n'
$'foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using tracing

Depending on your shell, trace debugging may or may not represent unprintable characters in an unambiguous way.

```
x=$(printf a\\rb)
(set -x; LC_ALL=C; : "$x")
```

results in a trace using the `$'…'` notation in shells that support it: for example ksh, mksh and bash all print

```
+ : $'a\rb'
```

But other shells, such as dash and BusyBox, just print the carriage return character to standard error, resulting in ambiguous output on a terminal, which I gather is what you want to avoid. If it's an option, run the script in bash or (m)ksh (or zsh in sh emulation mode) while debugging.

#### Using printf

Some printf implementations have a `q` specifier. `%q` is like `%s`, but quotes some characters in a way that allows the output to be parsed back into the shell. The result is also visually unambiguous, e.g. tabs are printed as `\t`. The GNU printf implementation also supports `%q`.

```
LC_ALL=C printf %q\\n "$x"
```

In dash on Linux, you have to use the external printf utility: `/usr/bin/printf`. In BusyBox, this feature is not available.

#### Piping through cat

Many implementations of `cat` can output non-printing characters in a visual way, e.g. tabs are `^I` rather than a bunch of spaces. Note that this is not unambiguous: a tab is indistinguishable from the two characters `^I`.

```
printf '%s\n' "$x" | cat -vet
```

#### Hex dump

You can print the output with a hexadecimal dump. The portable way to do this is with `od`.

```
$ x=$(printf a\\tc\\rb); printf %s "$x" | od -tx1'
0000000 61 09 63 0d 62
0000005
```

The BSD utility [`hexdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump&sourceid=opensearch) (`hd` for short), available on *BSD and on Debian-derived Linux distribution, also outputs printable characters, which is nicer.

```
$ x=$(printf a\\tc\\rb); printf %s "$x" | hd
00000000  61 09 63 0d 62                                    |a.c.b|
00000005
```

The popular utility [`xxd`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Hex_dump) (distributed with Vim, but available as a separate package in most distributions) has a similar output format.

```
$ x=$(printf a\\tc\\rb); printf %s "$x" | xxd -g1
00000000: 61 09 63 0d 62                                   a.c.b
```

#### The hard way

You can translate all the unprintable characters one by one using sed. Note that to make a portable script, you need to actually pass those printable characters to sed. If sed is called from a shell script, you can use `printf` to construct the sed script. The script below prints out the most common control characters as backslash escapes; add more if desired.

```
#!/bin/sh
export LC_ALL=C
sed_script=$(printf '
s/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g
s/'\''/\\\\'\''/g
s/\a/\\\\a/g
s/\b/\\\\b/g
s/\t/\\\\t/g
s/\f/\\\\f/g
s/\r/\\\\r/g
s/\033/\\\\e/g
$!s/$/\\\\n/
')
quoted=$(printf %sa "$2" | sed "$sed_script" | tr -d '\n')
printf "%s=\$'%s'\n" "$1" "${quoted%a}"
```

Usage: `quoted-dump x "$x"`

Comment: See also `od -vtc` to see the `\r`, `\n`.

Comment: `printf %q` does not always give a visually unambiguous output. See `\ue9` vs `e\u301`, and precomposed vs decomposed forms of thousands of characters, or the dozens of spacing characters most terminal represent the same, all the Unicode characters that look the same, the zero-width ones, the Unicode "control" characters that most leave as-is...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Even in the C locale? (Which I forgot to mention in that part of the answer, granted.)

Comment: I can't think of any beside the `O` vs `0` or `l` vs `1` which have identical glyphs in some fonts. ksh93's `printf %q` has an issue where it represents `$'\377x'` as `$'\xfff` even though it treats `$'\xfff'` as `$'\u{0fff}'` itself (expanded in UTF-8 even in the C locale).